# Add list view to Fluid template

Tags: templates, comments, typo3, fluid

I've built a custom extension which displays comments for a page.

But, of course, I want to have the comments section on every page. Is there a way to add it into the Fluid template so that I won't have to add it to every single page?

Looking for something like this:

```
<f:blabla.bla extension="tx_comment" action="list"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create your own viewhelper for this. You can use the VHS extension and use render.request

```
<v:render.request action="[string|NULL]" controller="[string|NULL]" extensionName="[string|NULL]" pluginName="[string|NULL]" vendorName="[string|NULL]" arguments="{foo: 'bar'}" onError="NULL" graceful="1">
    <!-- tag content - may be ignored! -->
</v:render.request>
```

https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Render/RequestViewHelper.html

Comment: This looks promising, but it still tells me `class:Tx_Kommentare_Controller_KommentarController maybe not loaded or no autoloader?`. Is there a quick solution you can come up with?

Comment: can you call your controller action directly without this error ?  try to clear your cache (rm -rf typo3temp/ and the tables cf_extbase_object & cf_extbase_reflection)

Comment: Since I was too lazy to access PhpMyAdmin I just cleared the temp via ssh and now it works like a charm. Thanks a lot!